# Rails 4 model not found during rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm new to Rails, and I'm experiencing an odd phenomenon - a model seems to go missing during testing.

I have models for users and accounts, with a members model to show which users belong to which account:

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, through: :members
  has_many :clients

  def self.create_with_admin(params={})
    account = new(params)
    if account.save
      account.users << account.admin
    end
    account
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  belongs_to :members
end
```

**member.rb**

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end
```

During the test, the following function located in the application_controller is run to return the account object associated with the users account (updated per comments):

```
1 def current_account
2   if user_signed_in?
3     @current_account ||= begin
4       user = env["warden"].user.id
5       member = Member.find_by user_id: user
6       Account.find member.account_id
7     end
8   end
9 end
```

**log**

```
Processing by Account::DashboardController#index as HTML   # this is the controller processing the 'current_account' function
"[ApplicationController.current_account] user: 65"
  Member Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 65]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Though warden authentication succeeds (i.e., env["warden"].user.id returns the currently signed in user's id), the function fails at line 5 with a "NoMethodError: undefined method for nil:nilClass". It would seem to me that the Member class is not being found, or that find_by is not a valid method for the model(?).

Is there an explanation for this situation, and what can I do to correct the issue?

Comment: If `env["warden"].user` is the same as `current_user`, I suggest using the latter.  That alone might solve your issue, but if not, then it will probably make it easier to debug.

Comment: Also, if it's not clear what part of the line is raising the `NoMethodError`, split it into 2 lines, i.e.:
`query = { user_id: env["warden"].user.id }`, and `member = Member.find_by query` one 2 separate lines